# localStorage.getItem returns null on other page

Tags: javascript, local-storage, opera-extension

I am trying to make an extension for Opera. I have an options page with `options.js`:

```
function saveOptions() {
    localStorage.setItem("secret", document.getElementById("secret").value);
}

function restoreOptions() {
    document.getElementById("secret").value = localStorage.getItem("secret") || '';
}

alert(localStorage.getItem("secret"));
restoreOptions();
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", saveOptions);
```

The alert shows the correct value for `secret`.

However, in the content script, the same alert line returns null. Why is this the case? How can it work on one page, but not on the other? How can I fix this?

Comment: Localstorage data won't persist through different domains

Comment: Then what should I use?

Comment: From the Opera extension docs: "You can use localStorage as defined in the Web Storage API to store user preferences for the extension."
Apart from that their documentation is trash.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage data won't persist through domains.

You can use `chrome.storage` as opera extensions are chromium based.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/